# store username to use in a later form

Tags: php

I have a form where I enter a username and it gets the users information. after calling for the users information I have another form wtih a checkbox for `"banned"` where I can ban or unban the user. But how can I store the entered username from the first form, to later use it in the second form where I check the banned checkbox?

code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="msform">
          <input type="text" name="datausername" placeholder="Username" maxlength="64" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/> 
          <input type="submit" name="userdata" value="Get Data" class="databutton">
        </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['userdata'])){
$datausername = $_POST['datausername'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$datausername'";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '

<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="flag note note--secondary">
    <div class="flag__body note__text" style="width:100%;">
      <h1>Personal Information</h1>
        ID : <div class="fr">'.$row['id'].'</div><br />
        E-mail: <div class="fr">'.$row['email'].'</div><br />
        Username: <div class="fr">'.$row['username'].'</div><br />
        Firstname: <div class="fr">'.$row['firstname'].'</div><br />
        Lastname: <div class="fr">'.$row['lastname'].'</div><br />
        <br />

        Activated: <div class="fr">'.$row['active'].'</div><br />
        Banned: <div class="fr">'.$row['banned'].'</div><br />
        <br />

     <h1>Data Information</h1>
        Title: <div class="fr">'.$row['title'].'</div><br />
        Rank: <div class="fr">'.$row['rank'].'</div><br />
        Level: <div class="fr">'.$row['level'].'</div><br />
        Exp: <div class="fr">'.$row['exp'].'</div><br />
        <br />

      <h1>Forum / Profile stats</h1>
        Forum Posts: <div class="fr">0</div><br />
        Forum Threaths: <div class="fr">0</div><br />
        Comments: <div class="fr">0</div><br />
        Awards: <div class="fr">0</div><br />
        Friends: <div class="fr">0</div><br />
        Followers: <div class="fr">0</div><br />
        <br />

      <h1>Security Information</h1>
        IP: <div class="fr">'.$row['ip'].'</div><br />
        Last IP: <div class="fr">'.$row['active_ip'].'</div><br />
        Secret Question: <div class="fr">'.$row['question'].'</div><br />
        Timestamp: <div class="fr">'.$row['timestamp'].'</div><br />
        Activate Link: <div class="fr"><a href="/activate/'.$row['activate_link'].'">link</a></div><br />
        <br />

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="note__close">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>';

if($title == 'Head Admin' || $title == 'Admin'){
  if($row['banned'] == '1'){
    $checkbox = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="confirm" checked/></label>';
  } else {
    $checkbox = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="confirm" /></label>';
  }

echo '
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%;">
  <div class="flag note note--secondary">
    <div class="flag__body note__text" style="width:100%;">
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <form method="post" action="" id="msform" style="text-align:left;">
        Ban: <div class="fr">'.$checkbox.'</div> 
          <div style="padding:10px;"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="dataset" value="Update" class="databutton">
      </form>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="note__close">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

        ';
    }
  }
} else {
    echo '
     <div class="container" style="margin:0 auto; width:100%;">
<div class="flag note note--secondary">
  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="flag__body note__text">
   User not found!
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="note__close">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </a>
</div>
</div>';
}
}
$db->close();
?>
```

This is the second form where I want to have the username stored to re use i to update the "banned" checkmark:

```
if($title == 'Head Admin' || $title == 'Admin'){
  if($row['banned'] == '1'){
    $checkbox = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="confirm" checked/></label>';
  } else {
    $checkbox = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="confirm" /></label>';
  }

echo '
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%;">
  <div class="flag note note--secondary">
    <div class="flag__body note__text" style="width:100%;">
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <form method="post" action="" id="msform" style="text-align:left;">
        Ban: <div class="fr">'.$checkbox.'</div> 
          <div style="padding:10px;"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="dataset" value="Update" class="databutton">
      </form>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="note__close">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: title in

```
if($title == 'Head Admin' || $title == 'Admin'){
```

Is your logged in title, so this will only be an option if you are either Head Admin or Admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hidden text field to store it, then pass it via the POST data to the next stage:

(instead of using datausername here, you should be using the row ID returned from your SQL query)

```
<form method="post" action="" id="msform" style="text-align:left;">
    Ban: <div class="fr">'.$checkbox.'</div> 
    <div style="padding:10px;"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="dataset" value="Update" class="databutton">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?=$datausername?>">
</form>
```

Then in the next stage $_POST['datausername'] will exist.

OR

Use sessions (the better solution to be honest, less prone to hacking)
For example, you can start a new session, shove some data into it and unset the session after your finished with it.

In your index.php / config.php / whatever

```
session_start();
```

In your php file:

```
$datausername = $_POST['datausername'];
$_SESSION['customdata']['username'] = $datausername;


if($title == 'Head Admin' || $title == 'Admin') {
    if ( isset($_SESSION['customdata']) ) {
       $username = $_SESSION['customdata']['userid'];

       //ban the user here, update SQL etc.

       //Unset the session variable
       unset($_SESSION['customdata'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form add a hidden field to contain the `id` of the user. You can then use that as a key for the update query in the second form

```
  <form method="post" action="" id="msform" style="text-align:left;">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    Ban: <div class="fr">'.$checkbox.'</div> 
      <div style="padding:10px;"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="dataset" value="Update" class="databutton">
  </form>
```

Alternativley use the session

In form one add thsi at the top of the script

```
<?php
session_start();
```

then load a value ito the session

```
$_SESSION['Users_id'] = $row['id'];
```

Now in the second form you will use that value in the UPDATE

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['users_id']) ) {
    $key = $_SESSION['users_id'];
} else {
    // we really should not be in this form
    header('Location: somewhere_else.php');
}
```

Comment: whouldnt this mean people could go into inspect element and change the value?

Comment: Yes it would mean that